# How to create JArray of JObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I'm trying to fill the object `details` with an array of `JObject`. The informations are available in the `contactAddresses` which is a `AddressModel[]`.

Whith the following code, I get the following error:

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered`

```
JArray addresses = new JArray();

foreach (AddressModel address in contactAddresses)
    {
        addresses.Add(JObject.Parse(
            @"{""street"":""" + address.Street +
            @"""city"":""" + address.City +
            @"""postalCode"":""" + address.PostalCode +
        @"""}"));
    }
    details.Add(new JProperty("addresses", addresses));
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the closing quotes around each data field, as well as the comma between them.  You need something like;

```
addresses.Add(JObject.Parse(
            @"{""street"":""" + address.Street + "\", " +
            @"""city"":""" + address.City + "\", " + 
            @"""postalCode"":""" + address.PostalCode + 
        @"""}"));
```

Comment: Filling stupid now... I'm not used to work with JSON in C#, syntax is pretty uggly. Thanks ! ;)

Comment: @Elfayer It doesn't have to be ugly. You could create a C# class that represents the data you want to serialize, then use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. It would be much cleaner. You may be able to reuse your AddressModel class for it.

Comment: @mason For the reading part, yes, but not for the data. The information in  `details` will depend on the contact type. So I'd have no choice but to add all possible properties to a `Details` class, even if most of the stays empty. I prefer to keep the "uggly part" to the backend code rather than receiving useless data to the frontend part.

Comment: @Elfayer So create different types to represent the different object types. You don't have to have ugly code. In fact, it's preferable not to.

Comment: @mason Agree, but I have to return this object to the frontend. So with different types, what's the return type ?

Comment: @Elfayer You haven't said what you're using or how you're returning it. Update your question to show that. For example, in Web API you'd just return `contactAddresses`. In MVC, you'd return a `JsonResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your ultimate goal is to end up with some JSON that represents a list of addresses. I know you mentioned JObject and JArray, but you thought that implementation was ugly. Here's an alternative.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contactAddresses);
```

The resulting `json` should look like this (once formatted):

```
[
    {"Street": "123 Mockingbird Lane", "City": "New York City", "PostalCode": "11111"},
    {"Street": "1600 Penn Ave", "City": "Washington DC", "PostalCode": "22222"},
    {"Street": "2400 University Dr", "City": "Fort Worth", "PostalCode": "33333"},
]
```

You can apply attributes to properties of the `AddressModel` class if you want the output to appear differently